# Is it resource-intensive to call KeyFactory.createKey?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Does it use a lot of resources to invoke `KeyFactory.createKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `createKey` simply constructs a `Key` object from the fields you provide, and doesn't require any RPC calls or other overhead. It's no more expensive than your average constructor.